# Is there a proper term for "mid-course students"?

Tags: terminology

I'm looking for a proper term for students that join a class mid-course. The suggested term I found was "mid-course student," but that doesn't seem to be an actual term.

"Transfer student" would be the perfect choice, but I'm looking for a term that doesn't include transferring, just late joining.

---

Newcomer is another term that seems to fit, but it doesn't necessarily refer to students.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It's not specific to the context, but have you considered "late entrants" or "late enrollees"?

You can replace the "late" with "mid-course" if it suits you better.